# ES6 modules syntax

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using babel-node CLI to run ES6 code on node.js and having some confusion on import/export syntax:

Both of these fail and throw Unexpected token error:

```
export * as default from './someModules';
export { * as default from } './someModules';
```

So what's the correct syntax to do the similar thing?

I also did this:

```
// module bla
import * as bla from './someModules';
console.log(bla); // successfully output the expected object
export default bla; // or tried export { bla as default }

// module blo
import bla from 'bla'; 
// bla is now undefined ??? I don't know why
```

On a side note, bla is in blo's peerDependencies, not sure if it affects. And btw, if I `export default {...} // a literal object` in module bla instead then the import in blo will successfully import that object.

Are these limitations of ES6 syntax, or limitation in babel-node, or some mistake from me?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html for good information regarding the proper modules syntax.

Comment: `export default bla;` should work just fine. And yes, there are currently some limitations regarding the `export` syntax. See the ES7 proposal: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from (which Babel also supports with the rights settings I believe).

Comment: @gustavohenke thanks but obviously I have read it many times already.
@FelixKling thanks for the link, it helped me confirm that the `export { * as ...} from ...` syntax is really not supported. However the `export default bla` case is very strange. `export default` a literal object works, a const/variable works, but the imported object doesn't work, even when I try `var a = bla; export default a`. I doubt if there's difference between a normal variable and the one which is `import *`'d, maybe because of babel transpiler

Comment: I tried Babel 6.1.2 with preset es2015, `import * as bla from ...; export default bla;` works fine.